# Count words difference between newest and old .tex file on SVN commit

Tags: revision-control, subversion, word-count

I use latex for writing papers and I would like to bring more control over my progress - in other words - count lines and words. But I always forget to check how many words I have before I start modifying a file.

I am using SVN to store latex files so I thought that maybe somebody wrote a script or a command line program  that would inform me on commit what is a different between old and new version of a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the SVN_EDITOR as described in the second answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983026/how-do-i-create-a-svn-commit-message-template-and-hook-to-verify

and dynamically create/alter the template doing additionally sth. like `wc myfile >> svn-commit.tmp`

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, `wc` will also count TeX code as words. It depends how accurate someone wants it. @Skarab: using `wc -l` and `wc -w` will only give you the line and word count, respectively.

Comment: Could you use [TeXcount](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/index.html) instead of `wc` to give a more accurate picture of actual words?

Comment: @Seamus: using `pdftotext` together with `wc -w` might be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Visual [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)-based tools are a nice way of viewing those differences. `diff` itself should give you enough information, but if you want something more informative (or easier to visualise), I suggest tools like [Kompare](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/) (screenshot [here](http://www.caffeinated.me.uk/kompare/screenshot.png)).